# Help me configure Spring-2 in netbeans6.8 step by step

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-mvc, netbeans6.8

Can Ony one help me to configure Spring2.0 and netbeans 6.8 step by step and also give me small demo example

Thnks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.  http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html